# Line two divs side by side inside a fieldset

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to place these two divs side by side with each other but no matter what attempt I make, even if it's worked on another page, I get a results that looks like this:

[image]

Here's the HTML (It's an MVC site so I'm using Razor):

```
<fieldset id="AgentTypeFields" style="width: 400px;" >
    <legend>Producer Info</legend>
    <div id="BasicsContainer" style="clear:both;">
        <div id="BasicsLeft" style="float: left;">
            <div class="M-editor-label" >
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReferenceNumberType)
            </div>   

            <div class="M-editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FormattedReferenceNumber)
            </div>  

            <div class="M-editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProducerType)<span class="req">*</span>
            </div> 

            <div class="M-editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EffectiveDate)<span class="req">*</span>
            </div> 

            <div class="M-editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JIT)&nbsp;
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.JIT)                        
            </div>

            <span id="ExternalRepId">
                <div class="M-editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ExtRepID)
                </div>
            </span>                                                                                             
        </div>
        <div id="BasicsRight" style="float:right;">

            <div class="M-editor-field" style="margin-right: 120px;" >
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ReferenceNumberType, "S") SSN
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ReferenceNumberType, "E") EIN                    
            </div>    

            <div class="M-editor-field" id="refNumber" style="margin-right:138px;">
                @if (ViewBag.FullSSN)
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FormattedReferenceNumber)
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.Raw("xxx-xx-")@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.displayLastFour)
                }                     
            </div> 

            <div class="M-editor-field" style="margin-right:82px;">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProducerType, (SelectList)ViewBag.ProducerChoices, new { id = "drpProducerType" })
            </div>   

            <div class="M-editor-field">          
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EffectiveDate, new { maxlength = 10 })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EffectiveDate)
            </div>

            <div class="M-editor-field">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HoldBool)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.HoldBool)
            </div>

            <span id="ExternalRepId">
                <div class="M-editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ExtRepID, new { maxlength = 40 })
                </div>                         
            </span>                                                                                            
        </div>                    
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Here is the pattern to follow: http://alistapart.com/article/prettyaccessibleforms

Answer (score 1):

Try setting Css `display: inline-block;` for child divs. one more issue is as width for your `fieldset` is `400px` both `divs` cannot be fitted inside it. Try setting it to `100%`

```
<fieldset id="AgentTypeFields" style="width: 100%;" >
    <legend>Producer Info</legend>
    <div id="BasicsContainer" style="clear:both;">
        <div id="BasicsLeft" style="display:inline-block;">
         ....
         ....
         </div>
         <div id="BasicsRight" style="display:inline-block;">
         ....
         ....
         </div>
     </div>
</fieldset>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tFymr/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the width on your floating divs, preferably to 50%.

Another solution is to use html tables or flex boxes

Comment: Never use tables for layout.

Comment: Their problem is lack of flexibility. In situations where you don't need flexibility, the act pretty solid actually.

Comment: Tables are actually more expensive in terms of rendering as well. Avoid using them for layout. CSS for Layout! Tables for displaying Data!

Comment: Tables are horrific, let along archaic, for layout.  Using CSS works far better than tables.